# 'Zooming' an orthographic camera whilst having certain sprites move relatively

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple environment, the user can draw objects such as boxes, triangles and circles. The environment looks as follows:

[image]

And with a few objects drawn:

[image]

The buttons in the bottom left corner are simply sprites children of the camera with an animation run when they are clicked.

There are two zoom tools, to zoom in and zoom out and they run with the following code:

```
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData EventData)
{
    if(CurrentTool == "ZoomIn Button")
    {
        TheCamera.orthographicSize -= 1f;
    }
    else if (CurrentTool == "ZoomOut Button")
    {
        TheCamera.orthographicSize += 1f;
    }
}
```

But this makes the buttons move like this:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way for me to have the buttons move with the camera so they're always in the same place to the user without completely changing the buttons system?

Comment: Use different canvases.  Have your shapes render on one canvas with `Screen Space - Camera` and put your buttons on another canvas with `Screen Space - Overlay` (you can set these in the inspector under "Render Mode").

Answer (score 2):

You should use Unity's UI Canvas for this instead of parenting your sprites to the camera. It's a bit more involved than you were hoping for, but Unity has a [quick tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-canvas) that you can use to get started. The gist of it is add an overlay canvas to your scene and add your buttons to that. The overlay canvas will always scale to the screen, no matter what the size or aspect ratio.

Comment: This is absolutely what you should do. Unity's UI system is essential to learn. Not only will it help with this sort of thing, but it will allow your game to function on devices with different screen sizes. I suspect if you tried that with the current code it would not be playable.